# Connecting Ribbon Cables to Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3

I'm a beginner with Raspberry Pi's and stuff like that. I was wondering if there was a way I could connect ribbon cables to the Pi? Maybe there is some sort of other board I could use. I would like to do this because I want to connect some devices to my Pi that have ribbon cables.

Comment: Can you give some examples of devices with ribbon cables that you plan to use (ideally a link to the product)? I'm worried you might be trying to connect legacy devices or PC HDDs to the RPI using a ribbon cable - this would definitely not work and could damage the device, the RPI or both.

Comment: Things such as a laptop keyboard

Comment: I've yet to encounter a laptop keyboard with a ribbon cable. What I think you're after is connectors for Flexible Flat Cable (FFC), which is more commonplace. The pi has a couple of those, but there's zero chance you'll be able to plug a laptop keyboard into them. Wrong everything - dimensions, pin count, pin arrangement, internal connections, software stack... it's a non-starter.

Comment: Can I plug my device into power socket? I want to do this because I have device with cord to plug into power socket.... me not understand

Answer (score 1):

Happily there's no problem whatsoever using ribbon cable with a Pi's GPIO. You need a [40-way 2.54mm/0.1" pitch connector](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/pcb-connectors/idc-connectors/#esid=4294957010&applied-dimensions=4294875494,4294881961&sort-by=P_breakPrice1&sort-order=asc) and some [suitable cable](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/cables-wires/ribbon-flat-cable/flat-ribbon-cable/#esid=4294957311&applied-dimensions=4294862299&sort-by=P_breakPrice1&sort-order=asc). [Adafruit sell them ready-made](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1988). They're fairly cheap, and straightforward to make yourself.

While ribbon cables can be really useful if you have *a lot* of stuff going on on your GPIO pins, or if you're putting some polish on your final product, it's a lot easier using [headed jumper wire](https://www.adafruit.com/categories/306) for making quick connections to things.

Comment: I would be careful - the OP is looking to connect devices that already have ribbon cables. Where I see how your answer is totally correct if the devices in question are RPi-specific peripherals, the OP might be trying to fit generic ribbon cables (such as those coming with HDDs) to the RPi's GPIO pins. This could potentially be disastrous.

Comment: +1 - I'm presuming that the devices are compatible in some way with the Pi. If they're not you're going to fry something. Just because the cable fits doesn't mean it's a good idea.